# Problemas con las validaciones usando Ajax en Rails

Tags: ajax, ruby-on-rails

Estoy intentando mostrar los errores de validación en Rails usando ajax en un modal, pero no logro mostrarlos, espero puedan ayudarme, agradeceré grandemente, comparto mi código:

**_form.html.erb**

```
<%= form_for @enterprise, remote: true, html: { multipart: true } do |f| %>

  <div id="error-messages"></div>    

  <div class="row">
    <div class="small-6 columns">
      <%= f.label :nombre %>
      <%= f.text_field :name, placeholder: "Nombre" %>
    </div>
    <div class="small-6 columns">
      <%= f.label :correo_electronico %>
      <%= f.text_field :email, placeholder: "Correo electronico" %>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="row">
    <div class="small-6 columns">
      <%= f.label :contraseña %>
      <%= f.text_field :password, placeholder: "Contraseña" %>
    </div>
    <div class="small-6 columns">
      <%= f.label :confirmar_contraseña %>
      <%= f.text_field :password_confirmation, placeholder: "Confirmar contraseña" %>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="row">
    <div class="small-12 columns">
      <%= f.submit "Guardar", class: "button" %>
    </div>
  </div>

<% end %>
```

**update.js.erb**

```
<% if @enterprise.errors.empty? %>
  $('#exampleModal1').foundation('close');
<% else %>
  $('#error_messages').html('<%= render partial: "enterprises/shared/errors" %>');
<% end %>
```

**enterprises/shared/_errors.html.erb**

```
<% if @enterprise.errors.any? %>
  <div id="error_explanation">
    <h2>
      <%= pluralize(@enterprise.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited
      this article from being saved:
    </h2>
    <ul>
      <% @enterprise.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
        <li><%= msg %></li>
      <% end %>
    </ul>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

**enterprises_controller.rb**

```
def update

    respond_to do |format|
      if @enterprise.update(enterprise_params)
        format.html { redirect_to admin_dashboard_path, notice: 'enterprise was successfully created.' }
        format.js   {}
        format.json { render json: @enterprise, status: :created, location: @enterprise }
      else
        format.html { render action: "edit" }
        format.js   { render action: "edit" }
        format.json { render json: @enterprise.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

Comment: Pero mas información por favor ¿te muestra algún error en consola de rails? ¿y en la consola de desarrollo? ¿Has verificado que efectivamente está cargando `update.js.erb` al generar un error? En la respuesta del servidor al retornar los errores de validación ¿te está haciendo un render del html contenido en `enterprises/shared/_errors.html.erb`? ¿Has verificado que efectivamente esté retornándote como respuesta `format.js` y no otra de tus 2 opciones?

Comment: Hola Alter, ya estuvo te agradezco mucho, en breve explico cual era mi error

Answer (score 1):

Problema solucionado =D Mi problema básicamente consistía en lo siguiente, si se fijan en el código, estoy intentando hacer un render a los errores, pero cuando el form se carga para crear o actualizar, se iba por **update.js**, pero de por si el llamado al render por alguna forma no lo hace, asique lo único que hice ya que aprovechando en el controller hago un render "edit", dentro de `format.js`, elimine el render y agregue de nuevo el código de errores en el form donde pertenece inicialmente y de esta forma los muestra sin ningún problema, en conclusion lo unico que se necesita es dejar el codigo de errores en el form o hacer un render simple sin js, y dentro de del controller dentro de update y create, agregar el `format.js {  render action: "edit" }` y va de maravilla =D